# Firebase RemoteConfig used for showing a message on app start

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I am thinking of using RemoteConfig for these 2 purposes:

1. Have on the server a parameter `minVersion` of the app that should function. So for instance if v1.5 is broken and I release an update on Google Play as v1.6 I want to block access to 1.5 and older and force the user to update to 1.6 in order to use the app.
2. Have on the server, a parameter to store a `message` to display in the app. So for instance have a `message` like "We are having server maintenance, please wait a while". On app start, if the message parameter is not empty, show a dialog with it in the app.

Of course, in this case, on each app start I need to fetch the remote config values and check them.
Why use `RemoteConfig`? Because it's easy, it's free, it's convenient and I don't need to have another separate server for these 2 simple jobs.

So is this a valid use case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes these are both valid cases. 
For point 1, you can quite easily determine the users app version. I created a video detailing how to do it 
https://youtu.be/McP11kcrMtk